# Git sees non-existent local changes and prevents pull

Tags: git

If I change a file, add my changes, commit them, and pull, Git claims that I have uncommitted changes. When I try to commit again, I receive a "nothing to commit, working tree clean" message.

```
[Annas-MacBook-Pro:Project Anya$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 4 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Annas-MacBook-Pro:Project Anya$ git pull origin master
anna@anna-git's password: 
From ssh://anna-git/git/Project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    index.html
    js/app.js
    sass/custom.scss
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I'm sure that I haven't changed the files again, but even if something had somehow changed them, it won't let me commit them again. Why does git think that I have local changes? How can I resolve this?

Comment: you're by chance using git from host machine to virtual machine?

Comment: I'm using it from a host to a remote machine, but not a virtual machine.

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR: you used `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree`

You use these flags to get Git to lie to you, so as to make things more convenient for you.  But now, the lie has come back to bite you.

#### Description

Note that `git pull` just means "run `git fetch`, then run a second command, usually `git merge`" and the error is coming from the `git merge` step.  So it's not exactly *pull* that fails; it's *merge* that fails.  This matters because the answer about why it fails, and what to do about it, is tied to using `git merge` and not to using `git pull`.  (This is one of many reasons I recommend avoiding `git pull`: it hides too much from you.  That's fine when everything *works*.... :-) )

There are two possible reasons for this kind of failure, distinguished by two slightly different different messages.  In both cases, we can say for sure that you have those *files*.

Here are the critical lines of the merge failure:

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>     index.html
>     js/app.js
>     sass/custom.scss
> ```

As an important side note, it refers to *local changes* to these files, rather than just "these local files".  The other form of this error message that begins instead `The following untracked working tree files`.  If you were getting that error, we would know something closely related, but not quite the same.

Here's the `git status` output:

> ```
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

This seems to be—heck, this *is*, given the phrasing of the first complaint—contradictory.  But there's an explanation for this, having to do with the *index*.

#### Git's index and `git status`

Git's *index* is, to a first approximation, where you build your *next* commit.  When you are mostly-ready to make a commit—have modified whatever work-tree files you want to modify, removed whatever work-tree files you want removed, and added whatever new work-tree files you want added—you must do *two* things to make the new commit:

1. update the index (usually with `git add`), and
2. run `git commit`

The reason is that `git commit` makes the new commit *from the index*, not from the work-tree.  So you must copy any new versions of files into the index, or remove any removed files from the index.

When you run `git status`, Git runs *two* `git diff`s.  One compares the *current commit*, known as `HEAD`, to the index.  The other compares the index to the work-tree.  The first `git diff` tells you what, if anything, you have already copied to the index so that it will be different in the *next* commit you make.  The second `git diff` tells you what, if anything, you have changed in your work-tree but *not* copied to the index, so that it must be `git add`ed before this will make it into your next commit.

The second `git diff` can also find *untracked* files.  An untracked file is simply "a file in the work-tree that is not in the index".  It really is this simple: the file *must* be in the work-tree, and *must not* be in the index, to be untracked.

Normally, when Git finds untracked files, it complains about them:  *Don't you want to commit this file?  Don't you?  Huh?  Huh?*  You can make it shut up about them by adding them to—listing their names, or a name pattern that matches them, in—a `.gitignore` file.  This makes Git shut up, but *does not* make the files untracked: that's still determined by "in work-tree, yet not in index".

Once the files *are* in the index, Git keeps telling you that your work-tree files are updated.  *Don't you want to commit this file?  Don't you?  Huh?  Huh?*  You can*not* shut Git up about this with `.gitignore`: the files are in the index; they are "tracked"; listing them in `.gitignore` has no effect.

#### Making Git lie to you

If you want Git to stop whining like a lost puppy, you can run `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree`.  This tells Git to set a flag bit on the index entry for the file: *Yes, this file may be modified.  But if it is, pretend it's not.*  Then `git status` won't keep saying *Don't you want to commit this file?  Don't you?  Huh?  Huh?*

But now that lie is a problem.

#### Checkout and merge (both are problematic)

Both `git checkout` and `git merge` use—and hence write on—the index and work-tree.  I'll describe `git checkout` here because it is simpler, but the problem is the same.  In many cases, for many files, when moving from one commit to another, Git doesn't *have to* write on the index and work-tree.  In almost all cases, though, it *does* have to write on the index and work-tree, for *some* files.

For instance, suppose you are on a commit whose hash ID is `badbeef`.  In that particular commit, there is a version of `index.html`.  Now you tell Git to check out a different commit, whose hash ID is `cafedad`.  In that particular commit, there is *also* a version of `js/app.js`.  But: are these the *same* version, or are they *different* versions, of `js/app.js`?

If they are *the same*, Git can move from `badbeef` to `cafedad` without touching `js/app.js` at all.  But if not, Git must *remove* the one that's in the index and work-tree, and replace them with the `js/app.js` from the *other* commit.

**If the index and work-tree versions of `js/app.js` match the `HEAD` commit version of `js/app.js`**, writing over the file is no big deal.  It's in the other commit: if you want the old version, you can get it out of the other commit.  **But if they don't match**, writing over them is a *huge* deal.  This might destroy precious file contents.

#### This is why your merge fails

What Git is telling you is that the commit you are merging *also* has those same three files, *and* it has a *different version* of those files than you have in your index and work-tree.  If you were to force Git to make the merge, this would *replace* your versions of those files with the other commit's versions of those files.  Therefore you must:

> ```
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
> ```

But `git status` says nothing at all, because *you told it to lie*.

#### The cure is to remove the lie request

You must tell Git to stop lying to you.  If you set `--assume-unchanged`, clear it with `--no-assume-unchanged`.  If you set `--skip-worktree`, clear it with `--no-skip-worktree`.  Now `git status` will show you reality.

Of course, there's a reason you set these in the first place.  So now you have to solve *that* problem instead.  Solve *that*, commit or stash your files, and merge, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I can see that these might also cause the problem, but I haven't used them in this case, and so setting those flags again doesn't solve for me.

Comment: It's possible that your Git version is old enough that it doesn't distinguish new untracked files from marked files. What version of Git *do* you have?

Comment: There was a branch i made another branch from, and when i had conflicts i had to pull the first and it started to see changes i didn't made, so i couldn't pull. I ended up deleting the branch and getting it again from git. Probably sourcetree made this mess.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I learned a lot here. And not just that `--assume-unchanged` would come back and bite me - I knew that when I set it (but of course I did it anyway and then forgot). But I learned a lot here - very well explained.